# Bigcommerce How can I set login and register links on header with fortune theme

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm using Fortune and the 'Login and Register' are at the bottom of the page. Does anyone know how to put it at the top of the page with the other headings.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code:

```
{{#if customer}}
        <li class="header-navigation-item navigation-item-primary">
          <a class="navigation-link-primary" href="{{urls.account.index}}">{{lang 'account_general.your_account'}}</a>
        </li>
        <li class="header-navigation-item navigation-item-primary">
          <a class="navigation-link-primary" href="{{urls.auth.logout}}">{{lang 'account_general.log_out'}}</a>
        </li>
    {{else}}
        <li class="header-navigation-item navigation-item-primary">
          <a class="navigation-link-primary" href="{{urls.auth.login}}">{{lang 'account_general.log_in'}}</a>
        </li>
        {{#if settings.account_creation_enabled}}
          <li class="header-navigation-item navigation-item-primary">
            <a class="navigation-link-primary" href="{{urls.auth.create_account}}">{{lang 'account_general.sign_up'}}</a>
          </li>
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
```